# Does 3DS Streetpass work in different regions?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, region-lock, streetpass

If I have a European 3DS (Italy), can I Streetpass a Japanese 3DS?

Is it possible to exchange data for region-locked games? I am especially interested in Streetpassing Monster Hunter Generations (European title) with Monster Hunter X (Japanese title). Could I exchange guild cards, palicoes, and so on?

Comment: International streetpasses are definitely working. I am however not sure if two different games can streetpass each other.

Comment: Actually it is the same game renamed. However in Europe it was released a month ago, in Japan instead last November so there might be small differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Streetpass works in different regions. I personally travel a lot and have streetpass-ed hundreds of people with 3DS from different regions on public transport.

About your second question, it seems that that is not possible due to the servers being different. [Source](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10163773210):

> Q: 海外版モンスターハンタークロス（Monster Hunter Generations）と日本のモンハンクロスは通信して一緒に遊べるのでしょうか？
>   フランスの友人がGenerationsを持っていて一緒にやりたいと言うので買おうと思うのですが…
>   A: 無理です。
>   国ごとです。

Comment: I spent 3 weeks in Japan, I got many streetpasses and actually some also for Monster hunter X. The names of some HMX players were Japanese, I do not know of course which version whey had.

Comment: However I got far more streetpass for other games even if Monster hunter franchise is extremely popular in Japan. Maybe I crossed people with EU version and Japanese name or some unlocked 3ds or rom.